# How to generate jmeter client using Swagger code-gen?

Tags: jmeter, swagger, swagger-codegen

I'm trying to generate a jmeter client using swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.3.jar as follows:

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.3.jar generate -i swagger.json -l jmeter
```

but it is giving me the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't load config class with name jmeter Available: aspnetcore
csharp
csharp-dotnet2
dynamic-html
html
html2
java
jaxrs-cxf-client
jaxrs-cxf
inflector
jaxrs-cxf-cdi
jaxrs-spec
jaxrs-jersey
jaxrs-di
jaxrs-resteasy-eap
jaxrs-resteasy
spring
openapi
openapi-yaml
kotlin-client
kotlin-server
php
scala
scala-akka-http-server
swift3
swift4
typescript-angular
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Is your API definition `swagger: '2.0'` or `openapi: 3.0.0`? JMeter codegen is currently available for `swagger: '2.0'` only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) free and open source automation framework in order to convert your Swagger JSON definition into Taurus YAML file which in its turn can be converted into a JMeter .jmx script.

1. [Install Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/install/Installation/)
2. Execute [`swagger2yaml` command](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Swagger/) like:

   ```
   swagger2yaml your_swagger_definition.json -o yourtest.yml
   ```

   it will generate `yourtest.yml` file in [Taurus YAML format](https://gettaurus.org/docs/YAMLTutorial/). At this stage you can alreay execute it using Taurus
3. If you want to convert the Taurus YAML script into JMeter .jmx script execute the following command:

   ```
   bzt yourtest.yml -gui
   ```

   it will open generated test in JMeter GUI, you will be able to save it to the desired location under the desired name normally from JMeter `File` menu

Check out [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus) article for more information on how to use Taurus tool.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to generate Jmeter client with below command with the latest openapi-generator-cli-4.1.2.jar

```
java -jar openapi-generator-cli-4.1.2.jar generate -i swagger.json -g jmeter
```

[image]
Please note I tried with swagger: "2.0" file